# An indeterminate equation

Tags: number-theory

Question: Calculate the indeterminate equation $x^2+y^2=z^4$, which satisfy $(x,y)=1,2|x$ and x,y,z are all positive integer. $(x,y)$ represents the greatest common divisor of x and y.
Below is my answer:
First, compute $x^2+y^2=(z^2)^2$. Obviously, we can get:
$x=2ab,y=a^2-b^2,z^2=a^2+b^2,a>b>0,(a,b)=1$, $a$'s parity and $b$'s parity are different.
Next, comput $z^2=a^2+b^2$. And we can get:
$a=2kw,b=k^2-w^2,z=k^2+w^2,k>w>(\sqrt2-1)k>0$ (to ensure that $a>b>0$),$(k,w)=1,$ $k$'s parity and $w$'s parity are different.
Or
$a=k^2-w^2,b=2kw,z=k^2+w^2,k>0,0<w<(\sqrt2-1)k$ (to ensure that $a>b>0$),$(k,w)=1,$ $k$'s parity and $w$'s parity are different.
So,the answer of the question is:
$x=4kw(k^2-w^2),y=4k^2w^2-(k^2-w^2)^2,z=k^2+w^2,k>w>(\sqrt2-1)k>0,$$(k,w)=1$, $k$'s parity and $w$'s parity are different.
or
$x=4(k^2-w^2)kw,y=(k^2-w^2)^2-4k^2w^2,z=k^2+w^2,k>0,0<w<(\sqrt2-1)k,$$(k,w)=1$, $k$'s parity and $w$'s parity are different.
I think my answer is a little complicated and I am not sure it is true. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From these equations one standard approach. That of which You speak.
the equation:  $$X^2+Y^2=Z^n$$

It is enough to write the formula generates an endless series of decisions in all degrees.  For this we use the Pythagorean triple.

And the number of their sets.  $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$  $$a=2ps$$  $$b=p^2-s^2$$  $$c=p^2+s^2$$
$p,s$ - what some integers.

Then the solution can be written.  $$X=2psc^{n-1}$$  $$Y=(p^2-s^2)c^{n-1}$$  $$Z=c^2$$

So there is always a solution.

Cutting will come to the formula about which You wrote.  For large degrees usually after receipt numbers should then be divided into common divisor.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, in my question the solution of the indeterminate equation should ensure that (x,y)=1, that is, x and y are relatively prime. In your solution, $(x,y)=c^{n-1}$.

Comment: The formula in the General form looks like this. This is done in order to avoid confusion with multiple solutions. Because coprime solution is not unique. There are multiples. They are often the same should be considered. Come to mutually simple solutions just always.  Divided by a common divisor.